# Trying to copy data from bmp file to a text file

Tags: c, copy, bmp

im trying to copy pixel data from a bmp file to a text file in c (white will be 0, every other color will be 1), but for some reason the text file comes out trippled (three areas of 1) and in the wrong direction, i cant figure out why. anyway this is my scipt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alloc.h>
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct {
unsigned char type1;                 /* Magic identifier            */
unsigned char type2;
unsigned int size;                       /* File size in bytes          */
unsigned int reserved;
unsigned long offset;                     /* Offset to image data, bytes */
} Header;
#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct {
unsigned int size;               /* Header size in bytes      */
int width,height;                /* Width and height of image */
unsigned short int planes;       /* Number of colour planes   */
unsigned short int bits;         /* Bits per pixel            */
unsigned int compression;        /* Compression type          */
unsigned int imagesize;          /* Image size in bytes       */
unsigned int xresolution,yresolution;     /* Pixels per meter          */
unsigned int ncolours;           /* Number of colours         */
unsigned int importantcolours;   /* Important colours         */
} Infoheader;

typedef struct
{   unsigned char Red, Green, Blue,Reserved;
} Pixel;


void main()
{
int n;
FILE *fin;
Header *fileheader;
Infoheader *information;
Pixel *ppixel,**pImage;
fin=fopen("TEST_web.bmp","rb");
    if (fin==NULL)
    {
    printf("Error reading image\n");
    exit(1);
    }
int i,j;
fileheader=(Header *)malloc(sizeof(Header));
information=(Infoheader *)malloc(sizeof(Infoheader));
ppixel=(Pixel *)malloc(sizeof(Pixel));
fread(fileheader,sizeof(Header),1,fin);
    if ((*fileheader).type1!='B'&&(*fileheader).type2!='M')
    {
    printf("Not a bmp file\n");
    exit(1);
    }
n=fread(information, sizeof(Infoheader),1,fin);
    if(n!=1)
    {
    printf("Error reading image information\n");
    exit(1);
    }
pImage = (Pixel **)malloc(sizeof(Pixel *) * information->height);
    for(i = 0; i < information->height; i++)
    {   pImage[i] = (Pixel *)malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * information->width);
    }
fseek(fin,fileheader->offset,SEEK_SET);
    for(i = 0; i < information->width; i++)

    {   for(j = 0; j < information->height; j++)

    {   fread(&(*ppixel).Red, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fin);

        fread(&(*ppixel).Green, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fin);

        fread(&(*ppixel).Blue, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fin);


        pImage[i][j] = *ppixel;

    }

}
char data[information->width][information->height];
        for(i = 0; i <information->width; i++)

        {   for(j= 0; j<information->height; j++)

            {   
                if((pImage[i][j]).Red==255&&(pImage[i][j]).Green==255&& Image[i][j]).Blue==255)
                data[i][j]='0';
                else
                data[i][j]='1';
            }
        }
FILE *fout;
fout=fopen("text.txt","wt");

for(i = 0; i < information->width; i++)

{   for(j = 0; j < information->width ; j++)

    {             fputc(data[i][j],fout);



}
fputs("\n",fout);
}

free(fileheader);
free(information);
free(ppixel);
for(i = 0; i < information->height; i++)
    free(pImage[i]);
fclose(fin);
```

}

[Im working for now with this picture](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/TEST_web.bmp)

Comment: OK, what did you find out while you were debugging the code?

Comment: Also please properly indent your code. Like this it's no fun reading it.

Comment: the wrong direction part seem to be on purpose in `for(i = information->width-1; i >=0; i--)`

Comment: also note that in BMP scanlines are padded with 0 so that the size of each scanline is divisible with 4

Comment: Please indent your code.  Also, compile and run it through a debugger like `gdb`.  That will help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for(i = 0; i < information->width; i++)    
{
    for(j = 0; j < information->height; j++)
```

use something like this:

```
for(y = 0; y < information->height; y++)    
{
    for(x = 0; x < information->width; x++)
```

(and of course do the same when you are scanning the bitmap.)

Comment: thanks for the help, sorry the mess, i always a bit messy in everything, ive tryed to make it a littile better.                                                                       about the padding im using digital mars complier, it dosent get 0, but it is padded (the Header is 14 bytes, the infoheader is 40 bytes).                                                      about the loops, well the only reason i did it oppside down is because ive read that the reading of the bytes of bmp file is oppside down, anyway if i change it to from 0 till the end i still get it oppside down and 3 times.

Comment: Yes, bitmaps are upside-down. (Usually or always, I do not remember.)  But I was not referring at all to the direction of counting along the Y axis.  I was referring to the fact that your Y loop must be the outer loop and your X loop must be the inner loop, not the other way around.

Comment: As for the triplicates, I do not know, maybe the problem will go away if you fix the nesting of your loops, maybe not, but I cannot really put much effort at reading your code because it is formatted horrendously.